# Unable to add Event Grid System-assigned Managed Identity to Storage Account Role

Tags: azure-storage, azure-managed-identity, azure-eventgrid

I'm unable to search for and assign an Event Grid SAMI to a Storage Account. It doesn't appear when searched for unless I select `Users` instead of `Managed Identity`.

**1. Azure Storage account (ADLS Gen2 w/ hierarchical namespaces)**

- `stgstackoverflowtest`

**2. Create a new Queue**

- `stgqueue`

[image]

**3. Create New Event and Subscription**

- Source: `stgstackoverflowtest`
- Trigger: When blob created
- Destination: `stgqueue`

[image]

**4. Enable System Assigned Managed Identity (SAMI) for EventGrid system topic**

[image]

**5. Add SAMI as Owner to Storage Account**

- Herein lies the problem(?). I can't select the SAMI because there is no option for "Event Grid"
- If instead of "Managed Identity", I select "Users" I'm able to locate the Event Grid system topic and add as owner

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from within the Event Grid Topic resource. Go to the blade `Identity` and then click the button `Azure role assigments`. From there it will show the way itself.

Alternatively Powershell and the Azure CLI commands would also work. An example using the CLI:

```
az role assignment create `
--assignee <GUID of the managed identity> `
--role 'Storage Queue Data Contributor' `
--scope /subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage>
```

Comment: Thank you. The SAMI technically *should* be available in the screenshots above though, correct?

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing they tried to make it accessible by limiting the choices to resources that mattered and it was forgotten by the time it got useful for event grid.